# On Windows 10, how to move a bunch of folders grouped into one folder multiple times?

Tags: windows, permissions, copy

Sorry if I don't word myself better,

basically I have these bunch of folders: F1, F2, F3, F4, ... , F1000

I want to automatically make new folders **and** group certain amount of these folders into them. Like it'd make a "New Folder" and put folder F1 through F10 in it, then it'll continue making the next "New Folder (1)" and put folder F11 through F20 in it, and so on until there's just not enough folders left.

The newly made folder's name isn't important, I can bulk rename them later, I just want to group them alphabetically/in order into several folders that's filled with 10 folders inside.

Summary:

what I have is Folder1, Folder2, Folder 3, Folder 4, .... , Folder1000

what I want is for Folder1 to Folder10 are moved inside a newly created folder, and then it'll automatically make new group-folder and move the next folders (Folder11 to Folder20) into it.

EDIT:
I have no knowledge of batch scripting, I've done my share like moving a bunch of files into a single folder, but not in multiple instances like this situations. Besides, all I do is just copying the script.

Anything I've looked up on either just move files to pre-determined folders and I have to specify them one by one in the batch script anyway.

The only thing I've tried as solution is to manually move the folders.

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: added more information on what I've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this `powershell` script, for example

```
$path = "C:\Temp\Test" # Change path here
$foldersPerFolder = 10

# Internal variables
$counter = 0;
$foldercounter = 0;
$folderDestination;

# Get all folders in path
$folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Directory | Sort-Object
# Enumerate all folders
Foreach ($folder in $folders){
    if (($counter % $foldersPerFolder -eq 0) -or ($counter -eq 0)){
        Write-Host "Modulo 10"
        $folderDestination = New-Item -Name "F$foldercounter" -ItemType "directory"
        $foldercounter++
    }
    Move-Item -Path $folder -Destination $folderDestination
    $counter++
}
```

However, keep in mind that this sorts alphabetically, which means Folder2 comes after Folder19 and before 20.

Comment: Is there any way to circumvent the 19, 2, 20 problem?

Comment: "which means Folder2 comes after Folder19 and before 20." is not a problem, I can bulk rename my folders to have several zeroes on front, I'll try this solution at work and come back later to respond

Comment: @Robert, easiest would be sorting by date for example, if possible. Otherwise you'll need to use a RegEx or someother split but this depends on the specific case.

Comment: @RobinF What you just said is above my understanding level. :)